# How to manage $_POST[] and $_SESSION[] to remember forms across multiple pages in PHP?

Tags: php, session, post

I'm playing with small exercise to understand sessions and posts, but can't get them to behave together. Can you help?

**Situation**

I have the following pages

1. **Page 1**
2. **Page 2**

On **page 1** I have a single input form.  The input is a checkbox, ex:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" >
```

- I want to be able to arrive at **page 1** without receiving errors
- I would like the unselected state of the checkbox to have a **`value of 0`**, and the selected state a **`value of 1`**
- Whatever value is assigned (by way of the checkbox), I would like that value stored in a session that can travel from **page 1** to **page 2** and *back*.
- Once a session value is stored, I would like to select or deselect the checkbox on **page 1** to change the value, allowing me to travel from **page 1** to **page 2** and *back* with the new value.

---

**Here is my code for this (which does not work):**

**Page 1**

Note: I have this code on the same page as the form. The `checkbox name="test"`

```
if (isset($_POST['test']))
{
$_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['test'];
}

if (empty($_SESSION['test']))
{
$_SESSION['test'] = 0;
}   
else
{
$_SESSION['test'] = 1;
}

var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
```

**Page 2**

```
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
```

---

Thanks in advance for you help.

---

**UPDATE**

If you would like to see the full code for both pages, I have posted them here:

**Page 1:**

http://www.diigo.com/item/note/17zt6/ux45

**Page 2:**

http://www.diigo.com/item/note/17zt6/gv6k

Comment: are you using `session_start();` on your pages?

Comment: what do you get when you do `var_dump($_POST['test'])`?

Comment: I get an undefined index error.

Comment: What are the values of `var_dump($_SESSION['test']);` on both the pages? Also, just to confirm you are calling the `session_start();` as the 1st line of code in both your pages?

Comment: Yes, on both. I have updated my original question and have added links to each page, so you can see the code yourself.  I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: I see the code is working fine. What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I can select the checkbox, but I can't unselect it. In other words, I can't change the value from 1 back to 0.

Comment: I have posted the code for your page 1 in Answer, that should work fine. Let me know in case of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for your page1.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['test']))
    {
        $_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['test'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
    }
}
if (empty($_SESSION['test']))
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
    $checked = '';
} 
else
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="page1.php" method="post">
        Test:
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test!">
    </form>
    <br />
    <a href="page2.php">Continue</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, this works great! I'm going to study it for a while. I hope I can come back and ask you questions if I have any. Thank you!

Comment: I do have a couple questions.. So I notice that you have tested on $_POST[submit] first. This is interesting. Why did you choose to do this? Also, can you explain why my code was not working?

Comment: First we have to check whether the session value has to be updated by checking whether the form was submitted. Only if the form was submitted the value of the session needs to be changed. After identifying that we want to change the session value we check if the checkbox was checked or not and accordingly set the value in session.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['test']))
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = true; // sets the session if the checkbox was set
} elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($_POST['test'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['test'])) unset($_SESSION['test']);
}

$checked = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    $checked = 'checked="checked"'; // check the checkbox by default if the session is set
}
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="test" '.$checked.'>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an undefined error for: if ($_SESSION['test']). Also, I can't toggle the checkbox. Once I select it, I can't unselect it.

Comment: Also, I don't think you're setting the values for the checkbox. It seems you're just changing the visual default state in the form. I need to have the checkbox values defined.

Comment: @Nathan you don't need values for checkboxes. checkboxes values aren't sent when not checked.

Comment: This also is not working. If I refresh my page, the checkbox is unchecked. Also, the session does not travel to page 2.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `if (!isset($_SESSION['test']))` instead of `if (empty($_SESSION['test']))` ?

Comment: You mean replace empty with !isset?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, bshrestha! This is not an answer. Add a comment on the question in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: It's an answer by any means, just not very well-written.

Comment: @bshrestha: Just add a second sentence to your question, why you think the one variant is better than the other so it's easier to understand to what you are referring to.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help achieve the results I'm going for. FYI, I quickly tested this, and it in fact does not help.